# What does "overheard" mean in this context?

Tags: word-choice

> Tocqueville’s, Madison’s or J.S. Mill’s criticism of democracy as a
> ‘tyranny of the majority’ is therefore well founded. This has led to
> corrective institutions, such as rule of law, basic rights for
> individuals, federalism or particular autonomy rights for regions and
> for minority groups. A further corrective element is political
> power-sharing. Lijphart, already in the first versions of his theory,
> proposed that consensus democracy is better suited than majoritarian
> institutions for multiculturally segmented societies. The theoretical
> reason is obvious: consensus democracy gives societal minorities a
> chance to participate in political power and have a voice in the
> policies of the government which cannot be overheard.
>
> *-Swiss Democracy by Wolf Linder*

What does overheard mean in this context?

According to Cambridge Dictionary overhear means:

- to hear what other people are saying without intending to and without their knowledge.

Comment: I think it's an error. The intended meaning seems to be "ignored" or "overlooked" but "overheard" does not mean these things. I see other subtle signs of translation from German (such as "already in the first versions...") which support this idea.

Comment: Thank you. Can we suppose that this text is translated from German by automatic translation? The reasion I'm asking is, there are a lot of errors in this "oficial release" book.

Comment: @AbbasMübariz I've added an answer, I'm not sure it has been the result of an automatic translation.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely a mistake. "Overheard", as you have found, means that something *has* been heard, either surreptitiously or unintentionally. It seems like they mean **overlooked**, which means *ignored*, either intentionally or unintentionally.

It has been suggested in comments that this may be due to a mistranslation from German - I'm not sure about that, as the German word 'Überhört' (literally 'over-hear') actually means to *mishear* - to not hear something properly - so it seems unlikely this word has been misused in your text due to an overly-literal or computer-generated translation. It is probably just an error, possibly based on the misconception that the word 'overlook' doesn't apply to things heard.

Comment: So, do I have to see the word as "mishear"? That is, one can not interpret the voice of minority incorrectly.

Comment: @AbbasMübariz No! I think it should be "overlooked". Based on the fact that, their *not* being overlooked is in contrast to minorities being ignored.

Comment: Mishear is actually _sich verhören_ (or _falsch hören_) in German. My other comment was actually referring to the phrase "already in the first versions" which is awkward in English but a very typical construction in German, and using this construction in English is a common mistake German-speaking people make (I live in Germany so I see a lot of this).

Comment: @TypeIA Right, "uberhört" is more like *failed* to hear something properly than hear something incorrectly. I've corrected that. Likewise, 'ubersehen' means to fail to see something.